# Get All Records With Single ID From Multiple IDs In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a blog page from where I send the category Id to fetch record from a blog table where category id match with the GET value.
Like this,

```
category-blog.php?catid=2
```

What I want is, that I want to fetch all records from a table in which the Get value ( i.e id ) is present. I have a blog table structure like,
[image]

Suppose, if my GET value is 2, I want to fetch all the records from the blog table where category_id is 2 present.

Sorry, for my bad English. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use   `FIND_IN_SET()` for comma separated value in table

```
 SELECT *
 FROM `tablename`
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2,`category_id`)
```

**UPDATED**

[As per documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - FIND_IN_SET's second argument is a comma separated list. So the value 2, 7 being split by a comma and space

**Solution**: stop using this approach and normalize your schema to use one-to-many (or many-to-many).

OR

remove space from your comma separated value

Comment: Have you run this query in phpmyadmin??

Comment: i try this   $categoryID = $_GET['catid'];
           
$getBlog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( `category_id`, '$categoryID' )");

Comment: use SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( category_id, $categoryID )

Comment: it still returns empty results :(

Comment: echo `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( category_id, '$categoryID' )` and paste your query\

Comment: above query o/p : SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( category_id, '2' )

Comment: okk try with `SELECT *
     FROM tablename
     WHERE FIND_IN_SET( `category_id`, ' 2' )`

Comment: the query returns only those record which contains the value at position i.e if my GET value is 2 then it returns output with all record because 2 is in first position ( see the above image ). But if I pass 8 it return 0 result because 8 is not in first position

Comment: because your string is 2, 7, 4, 8, 5 see space before comma . Try to remove space and make it 2,7,8,5 like this

Comment: thanks. it works after I remove spaces from my comma separated values. And yes the order should be like FIND_IN_SET(  2 ,`category_id`). But your suggestion works. thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET`

**EXAMPLE**

`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('ank','b,ank,of,monk');`

**OUTPUT**

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('ank','b,ank,of,monk'); 
+------------------------------------+
| FIND_IN_SET('ank','b,ank,of,monk') |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  2 | 
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Your Query**

```
$cat_ids = '2'; // OR $cat_ids = implode(',', array('2', '4', '1'));
// Use REPLACE to remove extra space between , and INT so that 1, 5, 2 becomes 1,5,2
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET($cat_ids, REPLACE(category_id, ', ', ','));
```

HELP LINK [FIND_IN_SET()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Comment: In `phpMyAdmin` run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('category_id', '2' );`.  `2` should be a string

Comment: $categoryID = $_GET['catid'];
           
$getBlog = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE FIND_IN_SET( `category_id`, '$categoryID' )");

Comment: i try this query but no result

Comment: Break it. Use `$sql = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( category_id, '$categoryID' )"; $getBlog = mysql_query($sql);` then `print_r($sql)` and paste the output of `$sql` here.

Comment: output : SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( category_id, '2' )

Comment: The query that I wrote also has `category_id` as string. `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'category_id', '2' )`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET(category_id, '2')` This Query is working fine here. You are using which version of MYSQL?

Comment: Are you sure the table name is correct? The query seems to be the correct one.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', category_id)`

Comment: the description of this function says that FIND_IN_SET returns the position of the string but i don't want the string position, i want the value present in the category_id table

Comment: SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET( '2', category_id )

Comment: Yes. You will get the value of the column `category_id`. It returns string position when you use it as a `field`. here you are using it as a `condition`

Comment: this query returns only that record which has the first matching value with the get value

Comment: What do you mean by 'get value' ? The query `SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', category_id)` will return all the possible rows having `2` in the `category_id` doesn't matter if its comma separated or at what position.

Comment: the query returns only those record which contains the value at position i.e if my GET value is 2 then it returns output with all record because 2 is in first position ( see the above image ). But if I pass 8 it return 0 result because 8 is not in first position

Comment: yeah but if I write it like this SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE FIND_IN_SET('8', category_id) then it gives zero result but it returns the record if only i out 2 instead of 8 because 2 is in the first position in the coloum

Comment: Thats not a problem with the query. Your DB values are separated not only with a `comma` but also with a `space`. You can modify the query to `FIND_IN_SET('2', REPLACE(category_id, ', ', ','))` so the final query will become `SELECT * FROM blog WHERE FIND_IN_SET('8', REPLACE(category_id, ', ', ','));`. I have editied the answer as well with the final query.

Comment: appreciate your help too !! enjoy

Comment: You got this one Saty. :P

Answer (score 0):

you must try with this

```
 SELECT *
 FROM blogs
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET( `category_id`, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `FIND_IN_SET()` for comma separated value in table

```
SELECT *
 FROM `tablename`
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',`category_id` ) > 0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in FIND_IN_SET(`search string`,`string list`), You are doing it in the reversed order. Thats why empty set.

Comment: the query returns only those record which contains the value at position i.e if my GET value is 2 then it returns output with all record because 2 is in first position ( see the above image ). But if I pass 8 it return 0 result because 8 is not in first position

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',`category_id`)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me in a while loop

```
$my_ids = $logged_ids; or $my_ids = 2;

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM campaigns WHERE FIND_IN_SET($my_ids, REPLACE(ids, ', ', ','))");
while($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo $result["ids"];

}
```